# Native Video Player Controls with Flutter (AVPlayer and ExoPlayer)

Tags: ios, flutter, avplayer, exoplayer

Flutter's video player plugin does not provide controls. Chewie Player is a commonly used plugin that gives the video player an interface.

However, the controls chewie provides are built IN Flutter. Is there a way to simply use the default video controls that I would use if I were building a native iOS app (AV Player) or Android app (ExoPlayer)?

example of iOS controls:
[image: iOS AVPlayer with Controls]

Comment: The best reply I got was [via a reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/x8juph/comment/inj2fdo/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), which indicated Platform channels are necessary.